# window.opener not working properly

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm trying to use a simple scenario in which function from parent window is called from a popup.My source looks like this:

#### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Parent window</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function twitterAccess() {
        console.log('ok!')
    }
    window.open ("popup.html","mywindow", "width=350,height=250");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>popup</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.twitterAccess()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But it allways gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'twitterAccess'`. I have also tried using it with `window.parent`, `parent.window`, `parent.window.opener` and a dozen of other suggestions found on the web but it's allways the same. Can you advice me on what am i doing wrong? I'm sure it's something really silly.

Comment: Which browsers are you testing this on? Could you say which work and which do not?

Comment: i'm using Google Chrome and none of those examples works.

Comment: Are you testing it from a `file:///` URL or a (local) web server? Chrome's same-origin policy is very strict, and blocks access if the local paths differ.

Comment: I'm using it on localhost (not `file://`)

Comment: Is `popup.html` loaded from the same domain?

Comment: yes, both are on localhost

Comment: Is that the actual code? I am betting `twitterAccess` is not global in the real version.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome. Are you assigning `window.opener` to anything?

Comment: @epascarello & Saravana - that's the actual code, 100% the same as i'm using.